# How to group values to centiles and calculate sum and average of other columns in sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a SQL Table in Oracle. I wanna generate in 1 query: centile (for the needs of example show quartile and group by probability but my dataset isnt sorted by probability), sum of score in each centile/quartile and average probability. My table looks like (with the differences that my desired output should be grouped in centiles not quartiles):

```py
 
#    ID      Score   Probability
#    1         1        0.9                   
#    2         1        0.8                   
#    3         0        0.6                   
#    4         1        0.6                  
#    5         0        0.5                  
#    6         0        0.4 
#    7         0        0.3                   
#    8         1        0.2
```

My desired output should look like:

```py
#    quartile  Sum_observations   Sum_score   Avg_probability
#    1         2                  2           0.85          
#    2         2                  1           0.6           
#    3         2                  0           0.45         
#    4         2                  1           0.25
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: n-tiles as ordered by what? By ID? What sense does that make? In most environments, the ordering of ID's has no meaning. Also, you say "grouped by probability" - what does that even mean? (Did you mean **ordered** by probability? But then quartiles as ordered by probability also makes no sense.)

Comment: I have probabilities for each ID from logistic regression and real observations in score. I wanted group every examples into centiles of probability and got sum of true values in each one.  @Gordon Linoff solved my problem very quickly and the result is what I expected.

Answer (score 1):

One method is `ntile()`:

```
select centile, count(*) as num_observations,
       sum(score) as sum_score,
       avg(probability)
from (select ntile(100) over (order by probability) as centile,
             t.*
      from t
     ) t
group by centile
order by centile;
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks for quick response ;)